# VUE3 Computed values inside v-data-table cells

Tags: vue.js, v-data-table

I am using v-data-table component in Vue3 to display tabular data. I would like to ask if its possible to let one of the table cells be a computed value or method which takes its input from other cells?

```
<script setup>

defineOptions({
data:()=>({
headers:[
{ key: 'calories', title: 'Calories' },
{ key: 'fat', title: 'Fat (g)' },
{ key: 'carbs', title: 'Carbs (g)' },
{ key: 'protein', title: 'Protein (g)' },
{ key: 'iron', title: 'Iron (%)' },
{ key: 'power', title: 'Power' },
],
desserts: [
{ 
 name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
 calories: 159,
 fat: 6.0,
 carbs: 24,
 protein: 4.0,
 iron: 1,
 power: << COMPUTED VALUE FROM OTHER CELLS IN SAME ROW >>,
}
],
})

</script>

<v-template>

    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts"></v-data-table>

</template>
```

I tried adding numbers and calling a function both worked.

```
desserts: [{ 
 power:1+1
}]
```

and

```
desserts:[{
 power:fnHelloWorld()
}]
```

worked. but I can't figure out how i can reference values of other cells in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive that using a computed value:

something like this :

```
<script setup>
  const headers = ref([
    { key: 'calories', title: 'Calories' },
    { key: 'fat', title: 'Fat (g)' },
    { key: 'carbs', title: 'Carbs (g)' },
    { key: 'protein', title: 'Protein (g)' },
    { key: 'iron', title: 'Iron (%)' },
    { key: 'power', title: 'Power' },
  ]);

  const desserts = ref([
    {
      name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
      calories: 159,
      fat: 6.0,
      carbs: 24,
      protein: 4.0,
      iron: 1,
    },
  ]);

  const processedDesserts = computed(() => desserts.value.map((dessert) => ({ ...dessert, power: dessert.iron + 1 })));
</script>

<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="processedDesserts"></v-data-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably use a `ref` variable that maps and calculates. Depending on your use case and if you plan on updating the original data (a computed property may not be needed or a ref)

```
const processedDesserts = ref(desserts.map((dessert) => {
   dessert.power = 1 + 1;
   return dessert;
}));
```

Then, call the mapped variable:

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="processedDesserts"></v-data-table>
```

If you do actually want a computed value that updates with your original data, I would set it with the computed value inside the object you want computed.

```
const processedDesserts = desserts.value.map((dessert: any) => {
  dessert.power = computed(() => dessert.calories * 10);
  return dessert;
});
```

Comment: Not a ref, but instead a computed

Comment: @DavidROSEY, what will be the benefit of using computed over ref here?

Comment: Here you are crating a ref which initial value is based on the value of another ref.
But if desserts.value change, processedDesserts will not be recalculated.
Creating a value based on another one, is exactly the goal of a computed value

Comment: Yeah, typically I'd agree, but given the data and the fact the object data is probably not going to need to be recalculated, I'd probably not worry about it in this instance. A ref probably isn't even needed, but it does actually depend on the use case. I'll put a computed example as well for values.